# Transacting in ATS Tokens

Tags: aion

I have created a custom token in mastery. I need to transact using the token on a java smart contract. How do I set the token type on the contract? I am using aion-web3 to call the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Any ATS token transfer is just a contract transaction of calling `send()` function in your token contract. 
Note: Java smart contract on Aion network can only interact with another java contract, not a solidity one.